# How to override magento\framework\view\page\config.php file in magento 2 for removing htmlentites in page source code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to override the magento\framework\view\page\config.php file setMetadata($name, $content) method to remove the htmlentites in meta description when we are viewing the page source code.

For that i did following code

di.xml file:

```
    <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config" type="Logo\Importer\Framework\View\Page\Config" />
```

Logo\Importer\Framework\View\Page\Config.php file:

```
<?php
namespace Logo\Importer\Framework\View\Page;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config
{
    public function setMetadata($name, $content)
    {
        $this->build();
        $this->metadata[$name] = htmlspecialchars($content);
    }
    
}
```

But its still not removing the htmlentities from page source code.

Any help can be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below possible solution which removes the HTML tags from the content.

Solution 1 : Magento way

```
echo $content_data = $this->escapeHtml($content);
```

Solution 2 : PHP way

```
$content = '<h1>welldone test</h1>';
echo strip_tags($content);
```